# C++ ADL: Call a function from the namespace which a particular type belongs to

Tags: c++

Imagine there is an existing type `Inner` in its own namespace. In this namespace there is a function/operator (`myfunc`) taking in the `Inner` type. Suppose, this function doesn't work properly, but we can't change it. Next, the type `Inner` is aliased within another class (`G`). That class belongs to a different namespace and defines a proper version of `myfunc` there. There is also a class template parametrized by `G`. When it calls `myfunc` ADL automatically selects the namespace of `Inner`. Is it possible to tell the compiler that it should call `myfunc` from the namespace of `G`?

```cpp
namespace ns1
{
    template <class T>
    class F
    {
    public:
        F()
        {
            typename T::I inner;

            // myfunc() is declared both in the namespace of T and T::I.
            // ADL picks up the innermost, i.e. T::I. Is it possible to 
            // tell the compiler that myfunc() must be selected from the 
            // namespace of T?
            myfunc(inner);
        }
    };
}

namespace ns3
{
    class Inner { };

    void myfunc(const Inner& i) {}
}

namespace ns2
{
    class G
    {
    public:
        using I = ns3::Inner;
    };
}

int main()
{
    ns1::F<ns2::G> f;
}
```

Generally speaking, is there any way in C++ to access the namespace of a particular entity? E.g. `namespace_of(SomeClass)::function_in_that_namespace()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to tell the compiler that it should call myfunc from the namespace of `G`?

No.

> Generally speaking, is there any way in C++ to access the namespace of a particular entity? E.g. `namespace_of(SomeClass)::function_in_that_namespace()`.

No.

---

You'll have to find a different approach, such as wrapping `myfunc` in another function, that uses `ADL` to call `myfunc` by default, but can be overloaded. Or something similar.